# blank page 1 and pdf plots not showing

Tags: syntax, workflow

my text is not going on to the next page properly.  I have been using LaTeX a long time but just updated some packages so I am sure there is some user error here. I found I mistakenly deleted "\begin{document}.  I added that so now have no page numbers, no plots, and page 1 is blank.

please see attached.[image: LaTeX not correct includes code]

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{pdfsync}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{ctable}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \doublespacing
    \textwidth      =  6.5 in
    \textheight     =  9.0 in
    \oddsidemargin  =  0.0 in
    \evensidemargin =  0.0 in
    \topmargin      =  0.0 in
    \headheight     =  0.0 in
    \headsep        =  0.0 in
    \parskip        =  0.0 in
    \parindent      =  0.3 in
    \pdfpagewidth   =  8.5 in
    \pdfpageheight  = 11.0 in
    \usepackage{underscore}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{color}
    \afterpage{\clearpage}
    \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
    \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
    \title{\vspace{-1.0ex}Chapter 6: The Results.}
    \date{}
    \maketitle
    \doublespace
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
    \doublespace
     \begin{document}
     \section{Introduction.}

       \subsection{Effects Plot: stuff.}
       \begin{figure}[h!]
      \caption{stuff plot.}\label{fig:onefig} \centerline{
     \includegraphics[width=4.0in]{blah_eff.pdf}}
      \end{figure} 
     \lipsum[5]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your preamble has some oddities. For instance, you're setting the page parameters with direct assignments instead of using `geometry`.

Note that `pdfsync` has been obsolete and deprecated for some years.

I reorganized the preamble in a more sensible way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{pdfsync} % obsolete and deprecated
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ctable}
%\usepackage{afterpage} % usually not needed
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\doublespacing
\geometry{
  letterpaper,
  width=6.5in,
  height=9in,
  headsep=0in,
}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}

\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}

\begin{document}

\title{Chapter 6: The Results.}
\author{}
\date{}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction.}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That cleared up many issues -- thanks you!!  but now my first page is blank?

Comment: @NikFord I guess you didn't remove `\afterpage{\clearpage}` or something like that.

Comment: actually no those are gone.  also on the blank page before my doc it says '138' at the top.

Comment: also none of my pdf plots are working now....

Comment: @NikFord A blank page with something strange is usually due to text before `\begin{document}` and should be accompanied by an error message.

Comment: what I have:\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\doublespacing
\geometry{
  letterpaper,
  width=6.5in,
  height=9in,
  headsep=0in,
}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\begin{document}

Comment: @NikFord Try to make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) using one of the example images from package [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe). But please: Don't use comments for such things.